# How to decode hex received?

Tags: c, sockets

I'm trying to decode a message that I am receiving from an SNMP trap. I'm receiving the trap fine, but when I try to decode it I just get a mess of characters. I do not want to use net-snmp libs in this listener.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SNMP_TRAP_PORT 162
#define MAX_MSG 1000

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int sd, rc, n, cliLen;
  struct sockaddr_in cliAddr, servAddr;
  char msg[MAX_MSG];

  /* socket creation */
  sd= socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
  if(sd<0) {
    printf("can't open socket \n");
    exit(1);
  }

  /* bind local server port */
  servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  servAddr.sin_port = htons(SNMP_TRAP_PORT);
  rc = bind (sd, (struct sockaddr *) &servAddr,sizeof(servAddr));
  if(rc<0) {
    printf("can't bind port number %d \n", SNMP_TRAP_PORT);
    exit(1);
  }

  printf("waiting for SNMP Traps on UDP port %d\n", SNMP_TRAP_PORT);

  /* server infinite loop */
  while(1) {

    /* init buffer */
    memset(msg,0x0,MAX_MSG);


    /* receive message */
    cliLen = sizeof(cliAddr);
    n = recvfrom(sd, msg, MAX_MSG, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &cliAddr, &cliLen);

    if(n<0) {
      printf("%s: cannot receive data \n",argv[0]);
      continue;
    }
    printf("Message size: %d\n", n);
    /*message is encoded with ASN1 and should be decoded*/
    /* print received message */
    printf("SNMP Trap received from %s : %o\n", inet_ntoa(cliAddr.sin_addr),msg);
    //printf("%p\n", &msg[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf("%02c ",  (unsigned char) msg[i]);
        //printf("%d", msg[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");


  }/* end of server infinite loop */
return 0;

}
```

What I get if I print hex

```
waiting for SNMP Traps on UDP port 162
Message size: 87
SNMP Trap received from 192.168.XX.XX : 34676050400
30 55 02 01 01 04 06 70 75 62 6c 69 63 a7 48 02 04 10 36 8d db 02 01 00 02 01 00 30 3a 30 10 06 08 2b 06 01 02 01 01 03 00 43 04 00 ef 8a df 30 17 06 0a 2b 06 01 06 03 01 01 04 01 00 06 09 2b 06 01 02 01 02 02 01 05 30 0d 06 08 2b 06 01 04 01 8f 65 0f 02 01 01
```

What I get if I try to cast char

```
waiting for SNMP Traps on UDP port 162
Message size: 87
SNMP Trap received from 192.168.XX.XX : 24711350560
0 U      p u b l i c ▒ H   L ▒ * ▒       0 : 0   +        C   ▒ ▒  0
  +     ▒ e      +         0
PuTTY
```

For reference, SNMP traps look like this... Which is what I'm hoping this hex will look like once it is decoded.

```
supercat
UDP: [192.168.XX.XX]:60734->[192.168.XX.XX]:162
DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance 1:17:26:53.28
SNMPv2-MIB::snmpTrapOID.0 IF-MIB::ifSpeed
UCD-SNMP-MIB::fileTable 1
```

So how do I decode this? I don't mind using other programming languages to decode if need be.

Comment: The data you receive isn't text, it's some kind of binary data that you need to parse in another way. Read the documentation for the trap message.

Comment: "I do not want to use net-snmp libs in this listener" Then you'll need to roll your own. As you've seen, there's going to be some work involved. Good places to start are the [SNMPv3 RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3414) (or earlier version) to understand the protocol and [net-snmp source](https://github.com/net-snmp/net-snmp) for a glimpse at how it's already been done.

Comment: maybe this will be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109737/how-to-receive-and-decode-snmp-traps-in-a-c-or-c-application

Comment: Unrelated – `memset`ting a buffer to whatever is just plain waste of CPU time if you are going to overwrite that buffer anyway...

Comment: That should be `%02X` for hex, not `%02c`,  `printf("%02X ", (unsigned char)msg[i]);`, you can use `%c` for printable characters, from 32 to 127 (or up to 256, but only if terminal supports it)

Comment: when comp;iling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings. (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results.  enabling the warnings results in LOTS of messages about problems in the posted code,